# Paper citation and search on google

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper (Privacy-Preserving Smart Parking System Using Blockchain and Private Information Retrieval) on arXiv two weeks ago, and whenever I search on the paper using 
google scholar, it shows me another paper (mobile information retrieval) which 
published in 2017.

Could you please help to fix this problem?

Comment: We are not Google Scholar or arXiv. Have you contacted either?

Answer (score 0):

It shows up correctly in a general Google Search. I think you just didn't wait long enough for the indexing behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok. See @Anyon's link above for more info about how articles appear on Google Scholar and at what speed. In particular, make sure your paper is hosted publicly on a university server somewhere.